# C# iTuneslib COM only showing collection classes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, com, itunes-sdk

After adding a reference to iTunes1.13typelibrary, and adding the 
 `using ituneslib;`
 In the program, I created the itunesApp class, but in the iTunesLib namespace, there are no options for classes such as `IITPlayList` or the track class, the only classes that show up are the collections. How do I access those classes?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve with this library exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to build a small application that fixes up songs in itunes, I wanna be able to browse through the library. I've seen working examples from other sources.

Comment: When you say "there are no options for" or "only classes that show up" are you talking about intellisense? You can most definitely declare objects of those types, but they for some reason don't show up in intellisense.

Comment: @roviuser , you're absolutely correct! I guess i'm pretty spoiled with VS2010's Intellisense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from comment: you **can** declare objects of these types, they just don't show up in intellisense. an example of this is here:

```
foreach (IITPlaylist pl in iTunes.LibrarySource.Playlists)
{
      foreach (IITTrack tr in pl.Tracks)
      {
           //do work 
      }
}
```

this code loops through each track in each playlist

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what you gonna do with the iTunes SDK. Sample application you can get [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/itunes_and_net.aspx)

Note: 
C# in iTunes SDK is supported via COM Interop. 
There're no managed interfaces in iTunes SDK and you have to release objects yourself to avoid memory leaks. 
When you access some iTunes SDK objects it launches iTunes application. 
Collections doesn't support IEnumerable interface, so you can't use *foreach* statement. 
It is very slow in the collections enumeration.

Comment: where did you get this info about memleaks and avoiding foreach?

Comment: @knocte it is from my personal experience - few years ago I had a project related to iTunes SDK, and if you do not release objects yourself the program took too much memory, the same with IEnumerable. But I will not argue about they support it already.